# R bayesglm: Estimates depends on order of variable

Tags: r, logistic, bayesian, regression-coefficients

I did a logistic regression with *bayesglm* from package *arm*. I got different results depending on the order of the variables in the model:

```
set.seed(334)
x1 <- rnorm(100)            # some continuous variables
x2 <- rnorm(100)
z  <- 1 + 0.6*x1 + 3*x2     # linear combination with a bias
pr <-  1/(1+exp(-z))        # pass through an inv-logit function
y  <- rbinom(100,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable


df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)

summary(bayesglm(y~x1+x2,data=df,family="binomial"))
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)   0.8673     0.3329   2.606  0.00917 ** 
# x1            0.5442     0.2790   1.951  0.05110 .  
# x2            2.8858     0.5540   5.209  1.9e-07 ***

summary(bayesglm(y~x2+x1,data=df,family="binomial"))
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)   0.8652     0.3318   2.607  0.00913 ** 
# x2            2.8492     0.5428   5.249 1.53e-07 ***
# x1            0.5757     0.2907   1.981  0.04761 *
```

I have no problem with this little differences even when the p-value is above or below 0.05 as in this example as long the difference is not too large and the estimates are similar. I'm just curious why this happened.

Comment: Set the random number seed before each calculation if you want identical results.

Comment: I did it. The estimates are still not identically (and remains like the output above). I think it is not a question of seed but how *bayesglm* does compute the estimates

Comment: Thank you for trying that experiment--it provides interesting information.